# url() return http while sever running on https

Tags: laravel, url, https

I'm create a web using laravel on a `https` website example: `https://examples.com`.
And I have a blade view which has a `form` with action to another page `https://examples.com/next`
I used this in my blade file: `<form action="{{url("next")}}" method="POST" id="page">`.

But when I test on browser, it show an warning like:
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://examples.com' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an insecure endpoint 'http://examples.com/next'. This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.`

When I inspect `<form>`, it show `<form action="http://examples.com/next" method="POST" id="page">`

Anyone has idea about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`url()` helper in laravel uses automatically http/https depending on the protocol of the request. If the page is `https://examples.com` it should generate `https` links.

If there is a proxy in place that switchs protocol, that error might happen. In that case you have two choices.

A local solution

```
<form action="{{secure_url("next")}}" method="POST" id="page">
```

a global solution

```php
//in app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php 
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
        if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') { //so you can work on it locally
            $url->forceScheme('https');
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Does it not look for the app url in the `.env` file?

Comment: @user3532758 The `APP_URL` in the `.env` file is used when generating urls with CLI, in request mode (fpm) it will uses `$_SERVER` variables and generate the link from it.